# media queries not taking effect on apple mail

Tags: html-email, email-templates

I created a responsive html email using the media queries method mentioned in this [article](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/). It works perfectly on outlook mobile app and its mentioned that it should work on iOS mail but it doesn't, any ideas how to fix that? This is the media queries part of the code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
          *[class="padding"] td, .padding td {
              padding: 24px !important;
          }
          
          *[class="mobile_scale"], .mobile_scale {
              width:100% !important;
              max-width: 100% !important;
              min-width: 100% !important;
            }
            
            *[class="shorten_space"], .shorten_space {
                height: 16px !important;
                line-height: 16px !important;
            }

            *[class="mobile_scale"] img, .mobile_scale img {
              width:100% !important;
              height: auto;
          }
          
          *[class="mobile_center"], .mobile_center {
              align-items: center !important;
              text-align: center !important;
              margin: 0 auto !important;
          }
          
          *[class="sub_button"], .sub_button {
              align-items: left !important;
              text-align: left;
              padding-top: 16px;
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Campaign Monitor's articles on email are very dated, unfortunately.

You don't need these at all: `*[class="shorten_space"]`. I believe from memory that was a hack to get classes working for Yahoo webmail, and they've updated years back so we don't need that anymore.

Just use the standard css, i.e. `.shorten_space`

(For all of them)

That would be a reason why it wouldn't on Gmail apps, though, not iOS. That's because Gmail removes all style blocks that it doesn't agree with.

I'd say the reason why it wasn't working for iOS, though, is becaues of the 375px limit. iPhones tend to be larger these days. Try bumping that up to 450px or so.